# Replacing newline with new rows in excel sheet

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am working with an excel sheet where rows inside a particular column is written using new lines.

[image: Fig1].

For e.g. in Fig 1. Col D and Col E have been represented using new lines. i.e. A = Very Good, Needs Improvement. What I am trying to get is this in another form as shown. Any pointers in this regard would be helpful.

[image: Fig 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use "Get&Transform" aka Powerquery.

Steps:

- Select your data and load it (with headers) into PQ.
- Add a new custom column (named 'Custom' for example) and use the following custom column formula:

  ```
  Table.FromColumns({Text.Split([Grades],"#(lf)"), Text.Split([Comment],"#(lf)")})
  ```
- On the newly created column, click the expand button (top right) and expand ***both*** columns.
- Delete columns 'Grades', 'Comments'.
- Additionally you could rename the last two columns back to 'Grades' and 'Comment'.

To make things a litle easier you could also just apply the following M-code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Table.FromColumns({Text.Split([Grades],"#(lf)"), Text.Split([Comment],"#(lf)")})),
    #"Expanded {0}" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Column1", "Column2"}, {"Custom.Column1", "Custom.Column2"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded {0}",{"Grades", "Comment"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom.Column1", "Grades"}, {"Custom.Column2", "Comment"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Your end result should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try esProc, split and expand multiline words in an excel cell into multiple rows as following code.

```
    A 
1   =file("data.xlsx").xlsimport@t() 
2   =A1.run(Grades=Grades.split("\n"),Comment=Comment.split("\n")) 
3   =A2.news(Grades.len();Names,Class,Year,Grades(#):Grades,Comment(#):Comment) 
4   =file("result.xlsx").xlsexport@t(A3)
```

For more explanation, see http://c.raqsoft.com/article/1609902051322

DISCLAIMER: This is about our tool esProc. It’s freemium.